# Automate clicking on Web Page button in C# ASP.NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net, mouseevent

I know this problem has been addressed here, but I cannot get any of the example code to work. Basically, I would like to simulate clicking on a button on a Web Page in a C# ASP.NET app. My code connects to web page but does not invoke click event.

Here is my code:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Navigate("URL to navigate to");
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("agree_terms_use").InvokeMember("click");
```

HTML:

```
<button id=agree_terms_use name="agreementValue" type="submit" value="Agree">Agree</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old now but I ran into the same issue (assuming this is to do with the Feds new E-Payment routing directory being moved and having a "Terms of Use/Agreement" page now).  Going off of your initial code I was able to get the below to work and create the file

```
//Load page that will end up as the "Agreement" page
WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

//submit agree button click
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("agree_terms_use").InvokeMember("Click");
webBrowser1.Document.Forms[1].InvokeMember("submit");

//Navigate back to the page which should now allow access to the data
WebBrowser webBrowser2 = new WebBrowser();
webBrowser2.Navigate(url);
while (webBrowser2.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();

HtmlElement body = webBrowser2.Document.Body;
string webResults = body.InnerHtml;
webResults = webResults.Replace("<PRE>", "").Replace("</PRE>", "");
webResults = webResults.Replace("&amp;", "&");

StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(outputFile);
file.Write(webResults);
file.Close();
```